# Pandas df.to_parquet write() got an unexpected keyword argument 'index' when ignoring index column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pyarrow

I am trying to export a pandas dataframe into a parquet format using the following:-

```
df.to_parquet("codeset.parquet", index=False)
```

I don't want to have index column in the parquet file so is this automatically done by `to_parquet` command or how can I get around this so that there is no `index` column included in the exported parquet.

Comment: Do you have an example of the dataframe you are looking to export?

Comment: what version of pandas are you using? that parameter only became available in 0.24 (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet.html)